# Sugarcrm module loader Scanning Package Error

Tags: php, linux, module, loader, sugarcrm

I am receiving the following error while installing any module:

```
    > Scanning Package 
    > Installation failed! 
    > The package you are attempting
    > to install does not conform to the policies established within the
    > Sugar Open Cloud or by your system administrator.


    >     Sugar Open Cloud customers must obtain a new package from the package provider that addresses the issues described below.
    >     If you are running Sugar locally, you can relax your Module Loader restrictions to allow the package to be installed.
    > 
    > The Sugar Open Cloud package loading policies are detailed in the
    > SugarCRM Knowledge Base. The available restrictions and exceptions are
    > detailed in the SugarCRM Developer Zone.
    > File Issues modules/let_Chat/history.php Invalid usage of a function
    > ob_start() modules/let_Chat/elements/sounds/button-19.mp3 Invalid file
    > extension modules/let_Chat/elements/sounds/Pop.aiff Invalid file
    > extension modules/let_Chat/elements/sounds/button-27.mp3 Invalid file
    > extension modules/let_Chat/elements/sounds/button-20.mp3 Invalid file
    > extension modules/let_Chat/elements/icons/restore_old.png Invalid
    > usage of a function '`' modules/let_Chat/show_chat.php Invalid usage
    > of a function $msi1() modules/let_Chat/JSON.php Invalid usage of a
    > function array_map() Invalid usage of a function array_map() Invalid
    > usage of a function array_map()
```

Please help me with resolving the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to install on the Sugar Open Cloud or your own Sugar instance?

Answer (score 1):

Sugar Open Cloud not allow some functions to be used in the package to be installed, [Check This](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2009/08/14/module-loader-restrictions/).
If you can change your configuration file than change `packageScan` to false in `config.php`.

```
  'moduleInstaller' => 
   array (
   'packageScan' => true,
   ),
```

Or

Add following array in `config.php` or `config_override.php` by adding all conflicting functions in it like.

`$sugar_config['moduleInstaller']['blackListExempt'] = array('unlink', 'ob_start',  );`

And do

`$GLOBALS[‘sugar_config’][‘moduleInstaller’][‘disableFileScan’] = true;`

If you cannot change configuration files than there is no solution than avoiding conflicting  function and files.

Answer (score 0):

$sugar_config['moduleInstaller']['packageScan'] = false;
set this on config_override.php to disable the package scanner